# c# change already open form from another form?

Tags: c#, forms, edit, toolstripmenu

C# windows forms:

Is it possible to create a button that changes the text of a ToolStripMenuItem in another form that is already open?

Something like:

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1.ToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Some_text";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if the menu created by the form designer the control will be private so you can create a public method or property in the form containing the menu to change the text and call it from the other form.

```
public void ChangeText(string Text){
   this.ToolStripMenuItem.Text = Text;
```

}

and then call it from outside

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, modify the Form1 designer code so that the private variable for ToolStripMenuItem is public rather than private.

Comment: How do I call a puclic void from another form?

Comment: I'm not somewhere I can verify this right now, but being explicit should do the trick, such as `Form1.myToolStrip.someToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Hey, it works!";`

Of course, I am not a developer.  Without the ability to verify, I'm sort of speculating.

Comment: From the property window change the modifier to public instead of private. I personally don't like that or recommended it you should only expose what necessary to outside.

Comment: I was about to ask how one is more secure than the other, but then realized that, with your method, it can ONLY change the Text value of the `ToolStripMenuItem`, whereas my suggestion of turning the entire `ToolStripMenuItem` public exposes the entire object to public modification.  Yours is obviously the better way.

Answer (score 0):

Just had a similar issue, here is my code:

```
public void UpdateStatusBarUp(string status)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                UpdateStatusBarUp(status);
            });
        }
        else
        {
            toolStripStatusLabelUp.Text = status;
            statusStripUp.Refresh();
        }
    }
```

please bear in mind the Refresh() that needed to actually make the change show up in the GUI.